# Get list of students having actions in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table of student actions (`id`, `student_id`, `type`, and `quarter`). I need to get a list of all the students, along w/ a flag of whether they had a particular action in the current quarter, and the past quarter but I'm not sure how to do this in Oracle SQL.

#### student_actions table

[image]

Assuming that the current quarter is 3, and that I'm only interested in the `Expulsion` and `Probation` actions how would I get a result set like the one I've mocked up below?

#### expected results

[image]

Comment: There are several traps in your "design"? How do you know when an action pass new year? Are the actions always in a sequence, i.e. without any gab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is simply an aggregation problem.

```
select
  student_id,
  count(case when type in ('Expulsion','Probation') and quarter=3-1 then 1 end) as previous,
  count(case when type in ('Expulsion','Probation') and quarter=3 then 1 end) as "CURRENT"
from student_actions
group by student_id;
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f4263/10/0

Comment: This query will fail if the table contains other data. I think the provided data are just examples.